# Hey guys, when i tried to run the following im getting an error " can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag"

Tags: node.js, typescript

E:\React-Projects\video-chat\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:421
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/server.ts:1:8 - error TS1259: Module '"E:/React-Projects/video-chat/node_modules/@types/express/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

1 import express, {Application} from "express";
         ~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts:108:1
    108 export = e;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.src/server.ts:2:8 - error TS1259: Module '"E:/React-Projects/video-chat/node_modules/@types/socket.io/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

2 import socketIO,{Server as SocketIOServer} from "socket.io";
         ~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/socket.io/index.d.ts:16:1
    16 export = SocketIO;
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.
    at createTSError (E:\React-Projects\video-chat\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:421:12)
    at reportTSError (E:\React-Projects\video-chat\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:425:19)
    at getOutput (E:\React-Projects\video-chat\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:553:36)
    at Object.compile (E:\React-Projects\video-chat\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:758:32)
    at Module.m._compile (E:\React-Projects\video-chat\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:837:43)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
    at Object.require.extensions. [as .ts] (E:\React-Projects\video-chat\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:840:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:19)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because your `tsconfig.json` file should have the `esModuleInterop` set to true in the `compilerOptions` section. Hope it helps